# A mailman sort 202 letters in N boxes. Does it means each box contain 1 letter?

Tags: probability

A mailman sort 202 letters in N boxes. Does it mean each box contain one letter?

Comment: Insufficient information.  You need to question the source of the problem as to their intent.

Comment: Your question isn't clear as $N$ can be any integer.

Comment: @AnotherUser Did you actually read the posting?  How is the original poster supposed to *show work* when all that they are asking for is a clarification of a problem statement?  Are they supposed to show that they looked up each word in the dictionary?

Comment: It depends on how you model it. If your interpretation makes sense, then why not. But of course there should always be the most senseble interpretation. But that does not mean that your interpretation is "useless". In this case I would say that the mailman sorts 202 letters in N boxes, where not every box has to contain a letter. So he might put all the letters in one box. But why should he not just put one letter in each box. I think it would be completly fine to view it like this. As I said, this is just part of your modelling.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, the mailman could sort all $202$ letters into one box and assuming there are no other boxes, then the mailman has sorted all $202$ letters in $N$ boxes, but each box does not contain one letter.

Answer (score 0):

If $N=1$ Yes

If $N>1$ No, because maybe all letters are put in one box and other boxes are empty.

Comment: For the $N=1$ case, I guess it depends on if you interpret "contains one letter" as meaning, "contains exactly one letter" or "contains at least one letter." That is probably what OP is *really* asking here. I'm not sure what the answer is, but in such cases I would find it ambiguous and ask the question-asker to clarify...